# Android Retrofit How to send token and refresh token when token expires

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I'm feel really lost right now and I don't know where exactly to begin. I manage a POST request (username,password) and recieved a response (token,refreshtoken). Saved it on sharedPreferences.

The first token expires after 10 min and I want to get a new token when response code hits 401. I'm really lost on this..

POST

```
interface APIInterface {
@POST("api/Tokens")
fun getAuthorizationToken(@Body tokenRequest: TokenRequest): Call<TokenResponse>

@POST("api/Tokens/refresh")
fun refreshAuthorizationToken(@Body refreshRequest: TokenRefreshRequest): Call<TokenResponse>
```

}

My sharedPreferences

```
class TokenManager(context: Context) {

private var prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(TOKEN_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

fun saveToken(token: String?, refreshToken: String?){
    val editor = prefs.edit()
    editor.apply {
        putString(USER_TOKEN, token)
        putString(REFRESH_TOKEN, refreshToken)
        putBoolean(IS_LOGGED_IN,true)
    }
    editor.apply()
    Log.d(TAG, "Shared preferences are added :$editor")
}

fun getToken(): String? {
   return prefs.getString(USER_TOKEN, null)
}

fun getRefreshToken(): String? {
    return prefs.getString(REFRESH_TOKEN, null)
}
```

}

My retrofit builder :

```
object RetrofitBuilder {

private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

val retrofit by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}

fun <T> buildService(service: Class<T>): T {
    return retrofit.create(service)
}
```

}

My AuthInterceptor where I don't know how to use it:

```
class AuthInterceptor (): Interceptor{


lateinit var tokenManager: TokenManager


override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
    val token = tokenManager.getToken()

    request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
    request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
    return chain.proceed(request.build())
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best implementation, but I tried.

First, I want to suggest that you rewrite your *TokenManager class*, since you chose to store the token in *SharedPreferences*:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences

object TokenManager {
    private const val USER_TOKEN = "USER_TOKEN"
    private const val REFRESH_TOKEN = "REFRESH_TOKEN"
    private const val IS_LOGGED_IN = "IS_LOGGED_IN"

    private var prefs: SharedPreferences? = null

    fun init(context : Context){
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.packageName, 0)
    }

    var token: String?
        get() = prefs?.getString(USER_TOKEN, null)
        set(value) {
            prefs?.edit()?.apply {
                putString(USER_TOKEN, value).apply()
                putBoolean(IS_LOGGED_IN, true)
            }
        }

    var refreshToken: String?
        get() = prefs?.getString(REFRESH_TOKEN, null)
        set(value) {
            prefs?.edit()?.putString(REFRESH_TOKEN, value)?.apply()
        }
}
```

*Notice how we use Kotlin's getters and setters.*

Don't forget to call the *init()* method in your *Application class*:

```
class YourApp: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        TokenManager.init(this)
    }
}
```

Now let's modify your *AuthInterceptor* and add checks with error codes:

```
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.Response
import java.io.IOException
import java.net.HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN as FORBIDDEN
import java.net.HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK as OK
import java.net.HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED as UNAUTHORIZED

class AuthInterceptor(private val retrofitBuilder: RetrofitBuilder) : Interceptor {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val originalRequest = chain.request()
        val authenticationRequest = request(originalRequest)
        val initialResponse = chain.proceed(authenticationRequest)

        if(initialResponse.code == UNAUTHORIZED || initialResponse.code == FORBIDDEN) {
            val responseNewToken = TokenManager.refreshToken?.let {
                retrofitBuilder.retrofitAuth()
                    .create(APIInterface::class.java)
                    .refreshAuthorizationToken(it).execute()
            }

            if(responseNewToken != null || responseNewToken?.code() == OK) {
                responseNewToken.body()?.let {
                    TokenManager.token = it.accessToken // your implementation
                    TokenManager.refreshToken = it.refreshToken // your implementation
                }
            }
        }
        val newAuthenticationRequest = request(originalRequest)
        return chain.proceed(newAuthenticationRequest)
    }

    private fun request(originalRequest: Request): Request {
        return originalRequest.newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ${TokenManager.token}")
            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .build()
    }
}
```

And the last class we'll touch on:

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

object RetrofitBuilder {

    private const val BASE_URL = "http://..."

    fun retrofitAuth(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(createClientAuth())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    private fun createClientAuth(): OkHttpClient {
        val okHttpClientBuilder: OkHttpClient.Builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()

        okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(AuthInterceptor(this))
        return okHttpClientBuilder.build()
    }
}
```

I saved all imports so you don't get confused.

I sincerely hope that I helped you

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to help me. The interceptor adds one header with TokenManager.token. The API requires one token and one refreshtoken. Should I add another header with the TokenManager.refreshtoken?